# Select max of literal values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, max, aggregate-functions

Why can't I do this?

```
SELECT MAX(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I'm just learning SQL and this is for learning purposes.
I expect the result to be 4, but I get an error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near ', 2, 3, 4)' at line 1

Comment: Try `SELECT MAX(val) FROM VALUES ((1),(2),(3),(4)) vals(val)`

Comment: @JonathanWillcock
This didn't work.
I got an error
`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ((1),(2),(3),(4)) vals(val)' at line 1`

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking for MAX here, but **GREATEST**:

```
SELECT GREATEST(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it with the MAX function.
I know it's ugly and probably no one will use it this way, but I wanted to do it with MAX
Here's the code

```
SELECT MAX(`values`) FROM(
    SELECT 1 AS `values`
    UNION
    SELECT 2
    UNION
    SELECT 3
    UNION
    SELECT 4
) a
```